# Duplicate interface definition error for class 'AppDelegate' and Property has a previous declaration error when using swiftvalidator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, validation, cocoapods

Im trying to implement uitextfield validation in my swift app using cocoapods framework SwiftValidator and im getting odd errors with one of the swiftvalidator delegate methods

i added swift validator to my podfile
podfile looks as follows

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'SwiftValidator', '2.1.1'
```

i imported swiftvalidator to my LoginViewController (which is a subclass of UIViewController) by declaring import SwiftValidator

my class is declared as

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, ValidationDelegate {
```

I initialised let validator = Validator() at the top level of the class

i added validator.registerField(emailField, errorLabel: emailErrorLabel, rules: [RequiredRule(), EmailRule()]) to viewdidload

i added skeleton of validationSuccessful delegate method as follows

```
func validationSuccessful() {
// submit the form
println("validation success")
}
```

but when i add other delegate method ie validationFailed as follows

```
func validationFailed(errors: [UITextField : ValidationError]){
    println("test")
}
```

it could be some type of cocoapods error but I'm unsure. Any suggestions?

Getting Duplicate interface definition for class 'AppDelegate' and
Property has a previous declaration
in the apps swift header file ie komunety-Swift.h

if i change the errors parameter in this delegate function ie to func validationFailed(errors: [UITextField : String] the error goes away ... ie it seems to be related to the ValidationError type itself

any ideas on how to fix

Answer (score 2):

For me it was using:

```
#import <Masonry/Masonry.h>
```

instead of

```
#import "Masonry.h"
```

Comment: Yes, Swift uses framworks,and by importing <> you will import the the framwork, #import "Masonary.h" will import only the header file.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in SwiftValidator 3.0.1. Check out [the issue here].(https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator/issues/50)

install instead:

```
pod 'SwiftValidator', '3.0.1'
```